# How to publish hostnames of Ubuntu machines using Avahi

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, avahi, mdns

How do you configure Avahi on Ubuntu to automatically broadcast and discover the DNS info for each Linux server on a local network?

I've ran this on my localhost (`hostname mylocalhost`) and a test server (`hostname mytestserver`), but all hostname lookups still fail:

```
$ sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon
$ sudo nano /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
    -#host-name=foo
    +host-name=<hostname>
    -#publish-addresses=yes
    +publish-addresses=yes
$ sudo service avahi-daemon restart
$ sudo update-rc.d avahi-daemon defaults
$ avahi-daemon --check
$ host mytestserver
Host mytestserver not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
$ host mytestserver.local
Host mytestserver.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
$ ping mytestserver
ping: unknown host mytestserver
$ ping mytestserver.local
ping: unknown host mytestserver.local
```

I've confirmed my firewall is disabled, so that shouldn't be blocking it. I've also read through Ubuntu's [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToZeroconf) on Zeroconf and mDNS, but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In my experience Avahi is not very reliable, and it's worth the hour or so it takes to set up a real domain (e.g. with FreeIPA).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ host mytestserver
Host mytestserver not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
$ ping mytestserver
ping: unknown host mytestserver
```

Hostname `mytestserver` is not in `/etc/hosts` nor local/lan dns setup. This has nothing to do with avahi.

---

```
$ host mytestserver.local
Host mytestserver.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
$ ping mytestserver.local
ping: unknown host mytestserver.local
```

This is related to avahi, check below.

---

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, the `hosts` line should be as follow:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

`files` means check /etc/hosts, then `mdns4_minimal` means check avahi.

---

There are a few things to check in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`.

In `server` section, `allow-interfaces` should be unset/commented, or have the interface you intended to use avahi:

```
#allow-interfaces=
```

Use `netstat` to check if `avahi` is listening on all interfaces:

```sh
# netstat -npl|grep avahi
udp  0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:* 696/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6 0 0 :::5353      :::*      696/avahi-daemon: r
```

I encountered a few cases that line was uncommented and with the wrong interface in it, blocking avahi on the intended network.

In `publish` section, set `publish-workstation` to yes (the default is no):

```
publish-workstation=yes
```

In general, `publish-addresses=yes`, which is the default, should be enough. However, with no share service(vnc/samba/etc) running, sometimes(base on past experience) avahi don't seems to publish/announce machine. So we enable `publish-workstation=yes` to force it.

---

One last note, sometimes it takes 2 to 5min for avahi to pickup others boxes.